# Create text with combinations of multiple arrays

Tags: bash

I have metrics like `route/api_1_test/POST/time/200.avg` where api_1_test is the `route`, POST is the `method`, time is the `metric_name`, 200 is the `status_code` and avg is the `metric_type`. I have arrays for route, method, status_code and metric_type. I would like to create a config file with all possible combinations of arrays with the following text

```
- name: finagle_route_<metric_name>
  path: $.route/<route>/<method>/<metric_name>/<status_code>.<metric_type>
  labels:
    route: <route>
    method: <method>
    status: <status_code>
    type: <metric_type>
```

How do I write a for loop for this?

Comment: for route in ... do for method in ... do for metric in ... (five nested) echo name...; echo path...; echo... (everything you need) done * 5

Comment: A basic bash nested loop should work in your case. Please show your efforts in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f

for route in $(<routes); do
    for method in $(<methods); do
        for name in $(<metric_names); do
            for code in $(<http_status_codes); do
                for type in $(<types); do
                    echo -e "- name: fingale_route_$name\n  path: \$.route/$route/$method/$name/$code.$type\n  labels:\n    status:$code\n    type:$type\n    method:$method\n    route:$route\n"
                done
            done
        done
    done
done
```